# Get PersonalUrl for a user without a SharePoint Profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

I'm in sort of a sticky situation. I need to find a way to get a OneDrive personal URL for users that lack a SharePoint user profile. I don't know how they can have a OneDrive without a proper SharePoint profile, but they do.

I can't find a SharePoint REST API call that lets me get that information if the profile is missing. I also can't figure out whether or not it's safe to generate a URL based on a template, since some tenants have a custom URL, they won't have _onmicrosoft in their personal URL, right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall where I had found this, but it was helpful to see who was using OD4B in our tenant using Powershell.

```
#Specify tenant admin and URL
$User = "you@your-tenant.com"

#Configure Site URL and User
$SiteURL = "https://yoursite-my.sharepoint.com"

#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site - required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)

#Bind to Site Collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#Identify users in the Site Collection
$Users = $Context.Web.SiteUsers
$Context.Load($Users)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Create People Manager object to retrieve profile data
$Output = "C:\Users\u531076\Desktop\Output.csv"
$Headings = "Name","Email","OneDrive URL","Phone","Job Title","Department"
$Headings -join "," | Out-File -Encoding default -FilePath $Output

$PeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($Context)
Foreach ($User in $Users)
    {
    $UserProfile = $PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor($User.LoginName)
    $Context.Load($UserProfile)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    If ($UserProfile.Email -ne $null)
        {
        $UPP = $UserProfile.UserProfileProperties
        Write-Host "Writing user data for " $UserProfile.DisplayName -ForegroundColor Green
        $Properties = $UserProfile.DisplayName.Replace(",", ""), $UserProfile.Email, $UserProfile.PersonalUrl, $UPP.WorkPhone, $UPP.'SPS-JobTitle'.Replace(",", ""), $UPP.Department
        $Properties -join "," | Out-File -Encoding default -Append -FilePath $Output
        }  
    }
}
```

It'll output a CSV and will provide you with the OD4B address or the generic link. I haven't ventured into trying to precreate OD4B spaces for users who have generic paths yet.

Comment: Well, that PowerShell script seems to rely on the PeopleManager, which only deals with users that have a SharePoint profile, so it doesn't really help... It looks like it might be useful in other situations though!

Comment: @Eric Alexander How can I get this information through the REST API?

Comment: @Ciddan Same question to you as well.